# Two fixed width full height columns, with seamless transition to blank space

Tags: css

[image]

I'm having trouble creating this design. The `#container` should be centered, with it's two children `#navigation` and `#content` stretching to the bottom of the browser. Like this for example.

```
#container {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#navigation {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#content {
  width: 760px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

But I don't know how I can create the colored blank spaces outside the container, which will blend in with the `#navigation` and `#content` creating a seamless transition from the `#container` to the blank space outside.

The transition between the `#navigation` and the `#content` should be the only visible.

I've tried floating the `#container` with two other div's containing the same background-color as `#navigation` and `#content`, but that messes it up, and trows it out of the center. How can I have my `#container` centered and have two div's on each side to fill in the remaining space?

Also, the blue and the red "blank" spaces was supposed to be equally wide. Besides that the drawing is accurate.

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @thirtydot Newer browsers. Not caring for IE6 anymore for that matter. Did you want a more specific answer?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://jsbin.com/amunuz

Comment: I added a jsbin for my answer too: http://jsbin.com/urokur

Comment: Both thirtydot and Ben Lee's solution worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See**: http://jsbin.com/amunuz

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 50%, #00a9ff 50%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(50%,#ff0000), color-stop(50%,#00a9ff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 50%,#00a9ff 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 50%,#00a9ff 50%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 50%,#00a9ff 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 50%,#00a9ff 50%);
  }
  #container {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #navigation {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    background: #ff0000;
  }
  #content {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #00a9ff;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="navigation">navigation</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is just my comment made into an answer.

Comment: Seems like the -moz, -webkit and -ms tags did the trick. I've never used them before so therefor no sufficient with them. Do you happen to have a site or resource where I could read up on this kind of thing? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Just Google "CSS3 gradients" for all the info you could ever want. In this case though, the CSS gradients aren't actually required. I just used them for convenience. You could replace them with a wide `background-image` with the two colours meeting in the middle, like this: http://jsbin.com/amunuz/2 (image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/P5NxB.png)

Comment: One more thing `display: table-cell` will work in all modern browsers except IE7, if that matters.