# Tricky CSS situation with centered page and two separate backgrounds on the left and right

Tags: html, css, layout

The attached image is what we want to achieve with html / css. The main points are that the page is 960px centered, the left column takes almost 1/3 of that and the right takes almost 2/3. Both sections are separated by the dark gray line. That's simple to do.

The problem is that on the left of the left section, we want the same background pattern as the one in the left section. And same for the right side. So on the right of the right section, we also want the light gray background pattern. Of course we don't know ahead of time how wide the browser will be open.

I'm looking for a clean browser independent solution - not a hack that works in some cases and in some cases doesn't. Also, if it's any help we're using LessCSS (casic CSS3 solutions work too).

Appreciate your input!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What elements do you have that are full width? Just `<html>`, or `<body>` too?

Comment: <html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>

Comment: I recently answered a very similar (identical?) question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903785/two-fixed-width-full-height-columns-with-seamless-transition-to-blank-space

Comment: @thirtydot let me take a look at it. looks like they might have something in common

Comment: @thirtydot read your code, there's a lot of things in there that i don't see the point of (all the gradient stuff and the table cell references). but what the core of what you suggested is to do a background-position:center for the body tag and have a thin height image that is super wide to cover any possibility of a screen resolution say something like 3500px... right?

Comment: That's more or less it. The gradient version does the same thing as the image version but well.. without an image. `display: table-cell` was used as a quick and easy way of ensuring equal height columns.

Comment: Great will keep that in mind. if you want to add your comments as an answer, let me know so i can upvote this solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get this done using CSS and JS (using jquery, but you could do similar stuff using pure JS).  I set the left/right to simply use different background colours - feel free to use images.

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#full {
    min-width: 960px;
    position: relative;
}

#dleft {
    min-width: 319px;
    background-color: darkGray;
    border-right: solid 3px gray;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px
}

#dright {
    min-width: 638px;
    background-color: lightGray;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.left-content {
    float: right;
    border-top: solid 1px gray;
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
    width: 299px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.right-content {
    float: left;
    border-top: solid 1px gray;
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
    width: 618px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
function resizeDivs()
{
    var WIDM = 960;
    var WIDL = 319;
    var WIDR = 638;

    var ww = $(window).width();

    if(ww <= WIDM)
    {
        $('#full').width(WIDM);
        $('#dleft').width(WIDL);
        $('#dright').width(WIDR);
    }
    else
    {
        var pad = (ww - WIDM) / 2;
        $('#full').width(ww);
        $('#dleft').width(WIDL + pad);
        $('#dright').width(WIDR + pad);
    }               
}

$(document).ready(resizeDivs);
$(window).resize(resizeDivs);
```

And, finally, HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="full">
        <div id='dleft'>
            <div class="left-content">
                Left Column
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='dright'>
            <div class="right-content">
                Right Column
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```