# Centered layout, one side to have bg pattern- the other a solid color

Tags: html, css, layout

My question is very close to this question:

[Two fixed width full height columns, with seamless transition to blank space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903785/two-fixed-width-full-height-columns-with-seamless-transition-to-blank-space)

*Except* I would like to use a bg pattern on the left side and have the right side be a seamless color. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it need to crossfade from pattern to solid color or just a solid line?

Comment: Michael, no crossfade or gradient. There will be a border (with drop shadow most likely) between 'navigation' and 'content'. also if I can have it default to the bg pattern for older browsers that would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Add a background property with a `repeat` (or `repeat-y`) value:

```
  #navigation {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    background: #fff url(http://placedog.com/400/300) scroll repeat-y top left;
  }
```

The `url` should point to the location of the background image on your server.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/amunuz/21/edit

Comment: I want the extra negative space left of #navigation to have the pattern as well. in your jsbin if the window is wide enough you still see red in the background...

Comment: Not exactly... The #container needs to stay a fixed width and be centered in the browser. Basically exactly like the sample I linked to except the red section needs to be a bg pattern. http://jsbin.com/urokur